# Convert SOAP Code to PHP

Tags: php, soap

I want to make Request and Response but I don't know how to do it into php. this is SOAP code:

The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
    POST /SMSGateway/Services/Messaging.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.smsbox.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendSMS xmlns="http://itbsms.com/">
      <sendingRequest>
        <IsBlink>boolean</IsBlink>
        <IsFlash>boolean</IsFlash>
        <RecipientNumbers>string</RecipientNumbers>
      </sendingRequest>
    </SendSMS>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendSMSResponse xmlns="http://itbsms.com/">
      <SendSMSResult>
        <RejectedNumbers>
          <string>string</string>
          <string>string</string>
        </RejectedNumbers>
      </SendSMSResult>
    </SendSMSResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Please kindly help me to make it into php. your help is very meaning to me. thank

Comment: Your question is very vague, you do not say what your actual problem is. First SOAP is nothing but http requests and responses with xml content, creating and parsing xml is not hard. But there even are convenient client and server implementations making SOAP communications easier. You will have to say however what you actually try to do...

Comment: can you help me how to do in php. I try to do it but I don't know how to do. thank

Comment: 1. you did not answer to my question, so I cannot help. Again: what is it you want to do? Server side or client side?  2. did you at least take a look at the implementations I mentioned?

Comment: what i want to do is I want to send SMS message from my website to client's telephone number. so I register with SMS Company then they give me this xml code that need me to make http request to there server to send sms.

Comment: OK, so you want to implement a soap client, not a soap server. http://php.net/manual/de/class.soapclient.php is a convenient soap client implementation, the documentation comes with lots of examples. As written above an alternative might be to use hard coded xml snippets instead, so you use a xml string, strew in some dynamic information and make a `cURL` post to the endpoint. Easier, but obviously less secure and less flexible.